# Oracle SQLPlus default configuration file location on GNU/Linux

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Does Oracle SQLPlus have configuration files for database host, pid, port and if so what are the default locations on a GNU/Linux host? In other words, when you invoke sqlplus from a Linux command line how does it know where to find the database to which to connect?

I have not been having any luck hunting through Oracle's online documentation.

Comment: [Read about TNS_ADMIN and default location](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_two.htm#i1133354). You can also try `locate tnsnames.ora` to see if a file exists; if not you can create one, or use [easy connect synta](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/netag/configuring-naming-methods.html#GUID-E5358DEA-D619-4B7B-A799-3D2F802500F1)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when you invoke sqlplus (from a linux command line) how does it know where to find the database to which to connect?

List of databases accessible to you is stored in TNSNAMES.ORA file. I don't know Linux, but - on MS Windows, it is stored in oracle home directory, \network\admin. I suppose you should be able to locate it.

In there, following the *syntax*, you create "aliases" to all your databases, by specifying host (or its IP address), port, SID or SERVICE_NAME. For example:

```
ORA10=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=my_db_server)
      (PORT=1523)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVICE_NAME=ORA10)
    )
  )
```

While connecting to the database, you have to supply the *connection string* which consists of username, password and the database. For example:

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@ora10
```

If there are several Oracle products installed, each of them has its own TNSNAMES.ORA file. In order NOT to maintain all of them (because, you'd want to connect to ORA10 from Forms Builder, SQL*Plus, Apex, ...), you can create TNS_ADMIN environment variable which points to a directory that holds one copy of the TNSNAMES.ORA file - in there, you keep all databases you're connecting to.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux/Unix, `sqlplus` searches for the `tnsnames.ora` file, looking sequentially in the

1. if it is defined `$TNS_ADMIN`
2. more often `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`
3. last chance `/etc`